# Remove a PyMongo SON Manipulator

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

For some queries in my application, I am using a SON manipulator to conveniently render database output. In some other cases, I just want the raw data.

So I add my manipulator thus:

```
db.add_son_manipulator(Renderer())
```

And here's my Renderer:

```
class Renderer(pymongo.son_manipulator.SONManipulator):
    def transform_outgoing(self, son, collection):
        rendered_data = {}

        for field in son:
            try:
                rendered_data[field] = son[field]['value']
            except (KeyError, TypeError):
                rendered_data[field] = son[field]

        return rendered_data
```

**Question:** How do I remove the manipulator from the database class instance for cases when I don't want my data transformed?

Comment: I don't understand your question: what do you mean remove manipulator from database?

Comment: @RafaelBarros I mean the database class instance. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

### EDITED

Seems it is impossible to do in a normal way (no API method exists for that purpose). Instead I should have another database object with no manipulator and use it when I don't need to transform the data (probably would work even faster).

Comment: @sssilver ok, so I edited answer to remove it at all.